# Why would the output of "last" show history less than the time I've had my laptop?

Tags: macos, unix

If I execute "last" in Terminal I see the following output:

```
Yonda     ttys000                   Wed Feb 19 18:03   still logged in
Yonda     console                   Tue Feb 18 23:21   still logged in
reboot    ~                         Tue Feb 18 23:21 
shutdown  ~                         Tue Feb 18 23:18 
Yonda     console                   Sun Feb 16 16:26 - 23:18 (2+06:52)
reboot    ~                         Sun Feb 16 16:26 
shutdown  ~                         Sun Feb 16 16:25 
root      console                   Sun Feb 16 16:24 - shutdown  (00:01)
Yonda     console                   Sun Feb 16 16:13 - 16:24  (00:10)
reboot    ~                         Sun Feb 16 16:13 
shutdown  ~                         Sun Feb 16 16:12 
Yonda     ttys001                   Sun Feb  9 16:09 - 16:09  (00:00)
Yonda     ttys001                   Sun Feb  9 15:56 - 15:56  (00:00)
Yonda     ttys001                   Thu Feb  6 11:01 - 11:01  (00:00)
Yonda     console                   Sat Feb  1 17:59 - 16:12 (14+22:13)
reboot    ~                         Sat Feb  1 17:58
```

It seems strange that this only goes back to Feb 1, when I've been using the laptop daily since well before Christmas.

I did recently update this laptop to High Sierra, potentially around that time.

My main concern is: is this an indication my laptop has been compromised?

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, no it is not an indication.

The "last" command much like other history commands essentially print out the history that is written to a log file that is stored somewhere. For instance, if I use the `history` command in zsh, it will print out the contents of `.zsh_history` and if I delete that and attempt the command again after starting a new terminal, I will no longer get that history.

What likely happened here, is that the OS upgrade cleared that log file, and the history started saving again after that. That is why you are not able to see those commands from before. There is little worry that your laptop has been compromised just because of this. Unless, someone took your computer, looked at your history and then deleted that log file. But why would they do that, you know.